# Aptana RadRails with Eclipse > 3.5 exceptions

Tags: aptana, radrails

I have been going back and forth over versions of Eclipse, and other IDEs, and I really want to use the latest Eclipse, it suites my tastes.  However, every once in a while, the thing goes mad, writing to the syslog the following:

(I'm about to go and try to find the missing class but I'm not even sure what the specific issues is yet.  I thought I might try here)

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.common.NotDefinedException: Cannot get the parent identifier from an undefined context. com.aptana.editor.php.presentation
at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.Context.getParentId(Context.java:201)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.getLevel(ContextSet.java:48)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.compare(ContextSet.java:37)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.compare(ContextSet.java:1)
at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1293)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1210)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:159)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet.<init>(ContextSet.java:76)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTableManager.createContextSet(BindingTableManager.java:88)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingServiceImpl.setContextIds(BindingServiceImpl.java:232)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:75)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:88)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:326)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:343)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.services.ContextContextService.deactivateContext(ContextContextService.java:71)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.contexts.ContextService$UpdateExpression$1.run(ContextService.java:131)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3935)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3612)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at com.aptana.git.ui.internal.actions.CommitHandler.doExecute(CommitHandler.java:34)
at com.aptana.git.ui.internal.actions.AbstractGitHandler.execute(AbstractGitHandler.java:108)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:68)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:226)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:207)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:123)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:142)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:704)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:609)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:593)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$3.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:552)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4125)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3971)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3610)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:969)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:885)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:87)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$3.run(Workbench.java:539)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:519)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem: to get rid of the exception, go to the plugins directory in your eclipse installation and delete the following files (or move them to some safe place):

```
com.aptana.editor.php_*.jar
com.aptana.editor.php.epl_*.jar
com.aptana.editor.php.formatter_*.jar
```

Of course, the php editor will not be available after that, so only use this workaround if you don't need php support.

**NOTE**: DO NOT open you workspace before deleting the php jars! Otherwise you will get  the exception even after the jars have been deleted.

Since I use Aptana Studio only for Ruby development, this worked for me on Eclipse e4 4.2. I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like I did this and they came back but I should give it another try.  I've been using RubyMine for my IDE but it might be worth giving Eclipse a shot again.